# How to make a discord bot send a picture you sent to it via dm to a certain channel

Tags: discord.js

So I kept thinking about this piece of code. The logic behind it is "you send the bot a screenshot via DM (direct message) and the bot is supposed to take that picture and put it to a certain channel that exists in a certain server (probably with id). The problem starts when I tell it to send the file, it just stops without an error happening on the console, sometimes it shows the answer "you successfully sent a screenshot" sometimes it does not. It is clear to me that it has a problem to realize that I am sending a picture instead of plain text, I guess?.

at this point, I am kinda stuck with not many options. (by the way, this block of code is attached on an "event")

```
client.on("message", message => {
message.author.send("Please send a screenshot");
const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === message.author.id, {});
console.log(collector)
collector.on('collect', message => {
    if (message.attachments.size > 0) {

        message.channel.send("You successfully sent a screenshot")
        console.log(`Collected ${message.content}`)
        client.channels.get(`628607857662623745`).send(message.content);

    } else if (message.attachments.size < 0) {
        message.channel.send("you did not");

    }
```

})

The bot is just required to send ONLY pictures you send it via DMs to a certain channel on discord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. You're collecting messages on the wrong channel

`Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === message.author.id, {});` will collect on `message.channel`, which is the channel the initial 'trigger' message was sent in, not the DMChannel. To collect on the DMChannel, you would need to do something like that:

```
if (initial_trigger) {
  message.author.createDM().then(dmc => {
    const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(
      dmc,
      m => m.author.id === message.author.id,
      {}
    );
    [...]
  });
}
```

### 2. You're sending back the wrong content

`` client.channels.get(`628607857662623745`).send(message.content); `` will only send the `message.content()` which, when you send a file without any comment, is empty. To send the file back and not the content, you will need to use `.sendFile()` like so:

```
console.log(`Collected ${message.attachments.size} screenshots`);
    client.channels
                .get(`628607857662623745`)
                .send({files:[message.attachments.first().url]});
```

Comment: It works as intented. it just gives me a warning that .sendfile function is deprecated which, as i see on the documentation it is replaced with just "Send". Thanks a lot, you really helped!

Comment: You're right, i edited my answer. I'm glad I helped!